# Agregar contenido a un archivo sin sobrescribir el contenido

Tags: java, filewriter

Como hacer posible que al **reiniciar la consola no sobrescriba** y **continúe escribiendo al final de la linea**.

Este es mi código :

```
import java.io.*;

public class RedirectSystemOut {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    PrintStream console = System.out;
    File file = new File("5.txt");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
    System.setOut(ps);
    System.out.println("This goes to out.txt");

    System.setOut(console);
    System.out.println("This also goes to the console");

  }
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo usar el try con recursos para que java se encargue de cerrar los flujos por ti , que ahora que me fijo no los cierras, me refiero a fos.close() console.close() y ps.close() cuando acabas de hacer las operaciones con el fichero https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html (Esto claro está si usas java 1.7 sino tendrías que usar si o si los .close())

Comment: Hola Nicolas, usa FileWritter y habilita la opción append (agregar).  @NicolasAlarcon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para que no sobreescriba el archivo usa la clase [**FileWritter**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) y habilita la opción [**append**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) (agregar).

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true); //opción append habilitada!
```

> [**FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html):
>
> Parámetros:
>   **fileName** - String con el nombre de archivo dependiente del sistema.
>
> **Append** - boolean si es `true`, entonces los datos se escribirán al final del archivo en lugar del comienzo.

---

este es un ejemplo en el cual si no existe por primera ocasión el archivo, lo crea y posteriormente agrega el texto al contenido.

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;

    try {
        String data = "Hola stackoverflow.com...";
        File file = new File("archivo.txt");
        // Si el archivo no existe, se crea!
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        // flag true, indica adjuntar información al archivo.
        fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(data);
        System.out.println("información agregada!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
                        //Cierra instancias de FileWriter y BufferedWriter
            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();
            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

El resultado sería un archivo con nombre archivo.txt el cual no sobreescribira el texto si no que lo agregará al contenido del archivo, algo similar a:

```
Hola stackoverflow.com...Hola stackoverflow.com...Hola stackoverflow.com...Hola stackoverflow.com...Hola stackoverflow.com...
```

Answer (score 3):

Usando este constructor aseguras que el fichero será abierto en modo sumatorio (append).

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

Aquí te dejo el hilo [write-file-without-deleting-older-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938886/write-file-without-deleting-older-data) con la resolución.