# Ir agregando lineas a un '.txt' y luego imprimirlas - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, archivo

Tengo tres Activitys, la principal:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] archivos = fileList();

    if (!existe(archivos, "notas.txt")) {
        crear();
    }
}

public void calcular(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Calcular.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
public void ver(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Ver.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

private boolean existe(String[] archivos, String archbusca) {
    for (int f = 0; f < archivos.length; f++)
        if (archbusca.equals(archivos[f]))
            return true;
    return false;
}

private void crear(){
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter archivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(
                "notas.txt", AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE));
    }catch(IOException e){}
}
}
```

Una que escribe los resultados de una operación en un '.txt':

```
public class Calcular extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText et1, et2;
private RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4;
private int r=3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calcular);

    et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);
    rb1 = findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb2 = findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    rb3 = findViewById(R.id.rb3);
    rb4 = findViewById(R.id.rb4);
}

public void operar(View v){
    int a, b;
    a = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
    b = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

    if(rb1.isChecked()){
        r = a + b;
    }
    else if(rb2.isChecked()){
        r = a - b;
    }
    else if(rb3.isChecked()){
        r = a * b;
    }
    else if(rb4.isChecked()){
        r = a / b;
    }

    try {
        FileWriter archivo = new FileWriter(getFileStreamPath("notas.txt"), true);
        archivo.write( String.valueOf(r) );
        archivo.flush();
        archivo.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
public void volver(View v){
    finish();
}
}
```

Y la otra debería leer e imprimir los resultados que se van acumulando:

```
public class Ver extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver);

    tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    try{
        InputStreamReader archivo = new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput("notas.txt"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(archivo);
        String linea = br.readLine().toString();
        String todo = "";
        while(linea != null){
            todo = todo + linea;
            linea = br.readLine().toString();
        }
        br.close();
        archivo.close();
        tv1.setText(todo);
    }catch(IOException e){}

}
public void volver(View v) {
    finish();
}
}
```

Pero sólo escribe el último resultado. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Gracias.

¿Puede ser que el método write() esté sobreescribiendo los valores que estaban almacenados?

Comment: Mira la respuesta a esta pregunta que es lo mismo que te pasa a ti: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/80831/30364

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente, el método `write()` está sobreescribiendo el archivo. Está escribiendo desde el inicio del archivo.

Una solución es usar `FileWriter` con la opcion [`append` (agregar)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)) activa. De la documentación podemos traducir algo así:

> Sí el segundo argumento es `true` entonces lo que escribas se agregará al final del archivo y no al inicio.

También usamos [`getFileStreamPath(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String)) en vez de `openFileOutput` para así obtener un objeto `File` directamente y que se pueda usar con `FileWriter(File, boolean)`

```
try {
        FileWriter archivo = new FileWriter(getFileStreamPath("notas.txt"), true);
        archivo.write( String.valueOf(r) );
        archivo.flush();
        archivo.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
```

Quizá querás considerar el usar `archivo.write( String.valueOf(r) + "\n");` para crear saltos de línea en el archivo.

Es bueno que sepas también que si vas a hacer varias escrituras seguidas en el archivos, podés optimizar el proceso usando [BufferedWriter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter)

Comment: Probé haciendo como decís, pero cuando abro el segundo Activity se cierra la aplicación. Edito para mostrar todo el código por si el error está en alguna otra parte.

Comment: Puede que con el cambio que hiciste, la naturaleza de tu pregunta y problema hayan cambiado. Sería de ayuda ver el error que muestra en tu consola.

Comment: En el EventLog no marca ningún error. El emulador sigue funcionando normalmente pero manda la aplicación a segundo plano y tira el mensaje "desafortunadamente, la aplicación se ha detenido". ¿Puede ser que falte manejar alguna excepción?

Comment: Si, puede ser. Tengo la corazonada de que tiene que ver con algun Stream que no se cerró de manera correcta. Revisa tu log hasta arriba, puede que despues del error la aplicación logee un monton de información dejando el error bien atras. O a veces me ha pasado que no lo marca en rojo como si fuera error, sino en normal.

Comment: No pude solucionarlo pero encontré otra forma de hacerlo guardando los resultados en una sola linea separados por barras y después remplazando las barras por saltos de linea.